# How to remove current view and add new view in iOS5 with ARC?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I want to remove the current view and add a new view which is switching from one view controller to the next in iOS5 with Automatic Reference Counting turned on.

Here's my current code:

```
- (IBAction)startClicked:(id)sender {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:@"flipTransitionToBack"];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

[YMobStartViewController removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview: YMainViewController];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

And I've imported the new viewcontroller's header, which probably wasn't necessary.

Under iOS4, I would allocate the new nib and display it but I'm not sure what to do to get rid of the old view and display the new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do the same thing as in non-ARC.  IBOutlet properties should have the strong attribute.  You just don't have to (and aren't allowed to) retain, release or autorelease.

But, this assume that you followed the pre-ARC coding conventions provided by Apple.

Comment: But I don't alloc/init right? Or do I alloc/init but don't release?

Comment: Yes, alloc/init the same as always.  All ARC does is insert the appropriate retain/release/autorelease behind the scenes (with an occasional optimization).